# Index notation in vector functions

Tags: notation, vectors

Suppose I have a vector $\vec u$ that depends on a vector $\vec x$ and a scalar t, so each component of $\vec u$ depend on all components of $\vec x$. How can I show this relationship with index notation?

$$ \vec u(\vec x, t) $$

From my understanding $u_i(x_i, t)$ 
implies:

$$ u_1(x_1, t) $$
$$ u_2(x_2, t) $$
$$ u_3(x_3, t) $$

wich is not correct, and 
$u_i(x_j, t) $ 
indicates:
$$ u_1(x_1, t) $$
$$ u_1(x_2, t) $$
$$ ... $$

which doesn't seem right either. I think the solution can be to write all the components for $\vec x$ but it is not very compact.
$$ u_i(x_1,x_2,x_3,t) $$

Comment: I'd write $\vec{u}(\vec{x},t) = (u_1(\vec{x},t),\cdots,u_n(\vec{x},t))$, but I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: @IvoTerek I was looking for a form who doesn't require ellipsis, and doesn't mix vector notation ( $\vec x$ ) with index notation ($x_i$), but maybe is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If the involved dimensions are not specified (and small!) you cannot do without ellipsis. We are talking here about a vector-valued function
$${\bf u}(\cdot,\cdot):\qquad ({\bf x},t)\mapsto {\bf u}({\bf x},t)\in{\mathbb R}^m\ ,$$
depending on the vector variable ${\bf x}\in{\mathbb R}^n$ and time $t\in{\mathbb R}$, or in coordinates:
$$(x_1,\ldots,x_n,t)\mapsto u_i(x_1,\ldots, x_n,t)\qquad(1\leq i\leq m)\ .$$